Proof of Fisher-Tippett-Gnedenko Theorem for arbitrary continuity point $x_0$ of $D(x)$
The Fisher-Tippet-Gnedenko Theorem states the class of extreme value distributions is $G_\gamma(ax+b)$ with $a > 0$, $b$ real, where
$$ G_\gamma (x) = \exp\left( -(1+\gamma x)^{-1/\gamma} \right), \quad 1+\gamma x > 0 $$
with $\gamma$ real and where for $\gamma = 0$ the right-hand side is interpreted as $\exp\left(-e^{-x} \right)$. The proof of this theorem is simple enough. I have attached a screenshot of the proof provided in Extreme Value Theory: An Introduction (2006) by Laurens de Haan and Ana Ferreira (see image, apologies in advance for the quality).

The first assumption of the proof is that $1$ is a continuity point of $D(x)$, which simplifies the proof in many ways. At the end of the proof, the authors state that one can instead use arbitrary $x_0$ as a continuity point and follow the proof as its written with some minor changes. I am precisely trying to do that.
When considering $x_0$ as a continuity point of $D(x)$ instead of $1$, the definition of $E(x)$ updates to
$$ E(x) = D(x) - D(x_0) $$
but the proof follows the same route until the expressions that would be equivalent to (1.1.13) through (1.1.15). I believe the equations following (1.1.15) would be roughly the same with some alteration of the definition of $Q$.
My question: What is the correct choice of $H(x)$, $s$ and $t$ when considering $x_0$ as the continuity point of $D(x)$ instead of $1$?
I have tried various shifts of $s$ and $t$ by multiples of $\log(x_0)$, and shifts of the argument of the original $H(x)$ by $\log(x_0)$ but with no success. I understand we are trying to get an expression that resembles the definition of the derivative, so I am thinking we need some limit of $s$ that represents $x \to x_0$ instead of the $x \to 1$ used in the original proof, but I have been unable to think of the correct choices of $H$, $s$, and $t$ to accomplish this goal.
